# How much side-to-side foot movement is possible in Crankbrothers clipless pedals?

Tags: pedals, pedals-clipless

*To be 100% clear I am not asking about rotating the foot, but moving side to side along pedal axis.*

The Crankbrothers cleat web page states there is -2/+2mm adjustment but this, as I understand it, refers to mounting/fixing the cleat (similar to SPD).

But I am interested how much movement is possible after the cleat is fixed, one is clipped in to the pedal. And I am asking because I would like to compare Crankbrothers (Candy 1 in my case) to Time ATAC pedals which are  supposed to provide 5 mm side to side movement (I hope this at least is accurate because I already learned that offset given for Time MX4 pedals is wrong).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I happen to use candy pedals so I measured how much I could move a shoe laterally on a pedal when clipped in - it's about 2mm.

However the pedal is holding the cleat quite tightly and and I'm pretty sure the cleat does not really 'float' laterally when riding. If the heel of the foot wants to move off the cleat centerline that is provided for by rotational float.

Answer (score 2):

Based on my experience with two pairs of different Crankbrothers clipless pedals and two pairs of cleats (one badly worn, another almost new), there is no lateral movement, or it is too small for me to notice when using the pedals. I would say my feet move more inside shoes than shoes happen to shift relatively to the pedal spring.

Comment: This is my experience as well